# Install nodejs issue

Tags: python, node.js

i'm following a tutorial i found to install nodejs and nmp bash
but after i tried to build the .deb package i get this message

```
if [ ! -r node -o ! -L node ]; then ln -fs out/Release/node node; fi
/usr/bin/python3.8 tools/install.py install '' '/usr/local'
installing /usr/local/bin/node
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tools/install.py", line 239, in <module>
    run(sys.argv[:])
  File "tools/install.py", line 233, in run
    if cmd == 'install': return files(install)
  File "tools/install.py", line 141, in files
    action([output_prefix + output_file], 'bin/' + output_file)
  File "tools/install.py", line 76, in install
    try_copy(path, dst)
  File "tools/install.py", line 66, in try_copy
    return shutil.copy2(source_path, target_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 433, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 372, in copystat
    lookup("utime")(dst, ns=(st.st_atime_ns, st.st_mtime_ns),
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:161: install] Error 1

****  Installation failed. Aborting package creation.

Cleaning up...OK

Bye.
```

command used to build

```
sudo fakeroot checkinstall -y --install=no --pkgversion $(echo $(pwd) | sed -n -re's/.+node-v(.+)$/\1/p') make -j$(($(nproc)+1)) install
```

Comment: I strongly advice you to use https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm to install Node.js - it's bullet proof and has always worked for me in various OS environments.

Comment: thanks @TsvetanGanev i'll try install with NVM